# why I am getting error as unexpected token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to **update employee salary** by using this query. Why I am getting `unexpected token:near line 1 in JPA Query` error.

```
 @Query("update employee set sal=  sal + 2000  where salary < :sal")
 void updateEmployeeSalary(@Param("sal") Long sal)
```

And this is my service method

```
 List<Employee> updateSalary(Long sal){
   repo.updateEmployeeSalary(sal);
   return repo.findAll();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to write a query like this

```
@Modifying
@query("update Employee e set e.salary = e.salary+2000 where e.salary< :sal")
```

Comment: how can I solve it? please help.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check once.

Comment: Please don't mislead users, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [@Modifying annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query):

```
@Modifying
@Query("update employee set sal=  sal + 2000  where salary < :sal")
 void updateEmployeeSalary(@Param("sal") Long sal)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform `Update` and `Delete` operation in `Spring Boot JPA` operation you want to declare `@Modifying` annotation

**Why declare `@Modifying` annotation ->**
To enhance the `@Query` annotation to execute not only SELECT queries but also INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and even DDL queries

**What if we forget to declare `@Modifiying` annotation ->**
Compiler throw exception `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` means query is not supported for `DML` operations.

`clearAutomatically=true` defines whether we should clear the underlying persistence context after executing the modifying query

Modified Repository:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
@query("update Employee set salary = salary + 2000 where salary< :sal")
```